# I am trying to return my documents in a RecyclerView although one of the fields is type timeStamp

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

One of my fields when returning my documents is type TimeStamp and it doesn't seem to return this. In my Session class where the get and set methods are for sessions, I am not sure what type to set startTime i.e. date or TimeStamp.

To clarify what i want to achieve: One of my fields in my session collection is of type timestamp, I want to retrieve this and display it in my recyclerview, I can retrieve and display this no problem in a normal view but i need to retrieve in recyclerview as i need to interact with the sessions.

Here is my current code.

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewHolder> {

DeleteSession deleteSession;
ArrayList<Session> sessionArrayList;

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(DeleteSession deleteSession, ArrayList<Session> sessionArrayList) {
    this.deleteSession = deleteSession;
    this.sessionArrayList = sessionArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(deleteSession.getBaseContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

    return new MyRecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.mModule.setText(sessionArrayList.get(position).getModule());
    holder.mTitle.setText(sessionArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.mDate.setText(sessionArrayList.get(position).getDate());
    holder.mRoom.setText(sessionArrayList.get(position).getRoom());
    //holder.mStartTime.setText(sessionArrayList.get(position).getStartTime()); THIS IS A TIMESTAMP IN FIRESTORE
    //
    holder.mDeleteSession.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteSession(position);
        }
    });

}

private void deleteSession(int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sessionArrayList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: What error are you facing ?

Comment: Do you have an error?